# Converting raw string data with fixed-position based schema into object based structure like JSON

Tags: javascript, python, json, performance, type-conversion

My use case is as follows,

Input format - String with fixed total length and each set of fixed positions represents some value.

Eg. Let input be `"ABCDE12345"` and consider position 1 to 3 `("ABC")` will represent field 1 value, position 4 to 7 `("DE12")` will represent field 2 value, position 8 to 10 `("345")` will represent field 3 value

Output format - An object-based structure like JSON

```
{
"field1" : "ABC",
"field2" : "DE12",
"field3" : "345"
}
```

My requirements in priority order are

1. Conversion from the input format to output format like JSON
2. Speed of conversion should be as fast as possible. Programming language can be chosen accordingly. Preferably js or python. Other languages are also welcome as a solution.
3. (Optional) How can we scale this solution for 1000s of conversion as quickly as possible?

Comment: And what have you tried so far, like splitting this string in three parts etc? I would love to write the code for your homework, but unfortunately you'd have to hire me :/

Comment: I tried a solution with java script. Step 1 - split using regex into array, step 2 - feed the array elements in order to a json structure. What i wanted is to look for different options from other programmers rather than fix my solution. Any solution that would satisfy my use case is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try this:

string_to_dict = lambda input_str: {"field1":input_str[:3], "field2":input_str[3:7],
"field3":input_str[7:]}
string_to_dict("ABCDE12345")

> {'field1': 'ABC', 'field2': 'DE12', 'field3': '345'}

2. speed depends on your input source. in case if you have pandas DataFrame you can maximize speed by applying this function to Series by using "map" function:

df['stinrg_series'].map(string_to_dict)

Answer (score 0):

If you prepare a data structure representing the fields with names and lengths in sequential order, you can apply it in a dictionary comprehension to split the data into individual keys and values.  Then use the json module to convert the dictionary

```
from itertools import accumulate
import json

structure = [("field1",3),("field2",2),("field3",5)]      # define names and lengths
positions = [0,*accumulate(size for _,size in structure)] # computed starting positions

data      = "ABCDE12345"
dictdata  = { name:data[pos:pos+size] for (name,size),pos in zip(structure,positions) }
jsondata  = json.dumps(dictdata)

print(jsondata)
# {"field1": "ABC", "field2": "DE", "field3": "12345"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```js
function strToObj(str, interface) {
  const outObj = {};
  let index = 0;

  Object.entries(interface).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    outObj[key] = str.slice(index, index + value);
    index = value
  });

  return JSON.stringify(outObj);
}

const testStr1 = 'ABCDE12345';
const testInterface1 = {
  key1: 3, // 'key1' will become the object key and 3 indicates the number of characters to use for the value
  key2: 4,
  key3: 3
}

const testStr2 = '+15417543010';
const testInterface2 = {
  intlPrefix: 2,
  localPrefix: 3,
  phonenumber: 7
}

console.log(strToObj(testStr1, testInterface1));
console.log(strToObj(testStr2, testInterface2));
```

Or a simplified version, if you do not need to create a reusable function